# Disable Prompt to "please unlock iPhone" Photos 8.0

Tags: iphone, photos.app, data-synchronization

When I plug my iPhone 11 into my M1 Macbook running Ventura(MacOS v13.5), Photos v8 prompts me to unlock my iPhone, ostensibly to sync photos from the device. Can I prevent this behavior? I sync photos from my phone to the Photos library using iCloud, so I don't want or need to sync the same data twice.

I remember the being another app where you could disable the sync , but it's been years since I used that app to disable the syncing my iPhone with Photos. Google search hasn't turned up any useful results either, so I'm asking here.

Comment: I would assume that this request to unlock the iPhone connected to the computer is more for your privacy and safety of your content than anything else.

Comment: @ErniePC12 - yes, you need to unlock the phone for any data transfer from it - it's just that Photos is set up by default to do this import automatically; which wasn't an issue in the early days before iOS was locked down so tightly. The pref to switch if off, however, is not easy to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most easily done from Image Capture - which you can do without even unlocking the phone - because you're setting a pref in the Mac, not in the phone.

Connect your phone, set 'Connecting this camera opens:' to No application. You can then eject or simply unplug the phone again.
This can be done for any camera device or USB stick/SD card from a camera. Each setting is remembered only for that device.

[image]

<sup>Picture from Mojave. Ventura looks similar [but I don't have a phone I can quickly plug into it.]</sup>